# How to toggle file names in Windows 7 command-line

Tags: windows-7, cmd

I want to toggle the names of two files, using a batch file (Windows 7 command-line). I wrote the following code, but its not working.

```
IF EXIST test12.txt
rename test.txt test23.txt
rename test12.txt test.txt
```

Could someone help me correct this code?

Thanks.

EDIT: When I run from the command line, it says "The syntax of the command is incorrect". What is the syntax then? Is this only for checking the existence of directories?

Comment: What makes you say it's not working? What are you observing? How would someone reading your question reproduce it?

Comment: Sorry... I meant Windows 7 command line. When I run the batch file(by dbl clicking it), I did not see any change to the file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are asking. Perhaps your IF clause isn't correct. By using () the code should improve.

```
IF EXIST test12.txt (
    rename test.txt test23.txt
    rename test12.txt test.txt
)
```

Comment: Thanks... this worked. I think I found an old example, so it did not work.